# How to save d3 selections in an array for later use D3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm attempting to save selections of circles in an array so I can later manipulate those circles without having to search through all the circles on the page. I want to be able to access the circles from a different function than then one they are created in.

```
// From outer function
var selections = [];

// From inner function A
circles.on("click", function(da){
  d3.selectAll("circle").filter(function(db){
    var result = da.someProperty == db.someProperty;
    var circle = d3.select(this);
    if(result) selections.push(circle);
    return result;
  })
  .attr("fill", "red");
});

// From inner function B
selections.forEach(function(circle){
  circle.attr("fill", "black");        // Doesn't work
});
```

Is there a way to modify the circle attributes using the contents of my selections array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your selections.forEach(...), take a look at what "circle" actually is. From what I've tested (I had to create the variable "circles" ahead of time, which is just d3.selectAll('circle'), but you should really include specifically what you're working with in your prompt), "circle" in your function B loop refers to a  1-cell array holding another a 1-cell array, which holds a circle reference (to a native HTML/SVG circle, NOT a d3 wrapper).

Change the contents of the B loop's function to

```
d3.select(circle[0][0]).attr('fill','black');
```

Perhaps there's a more elegant, d3-oriented way, but this definitely works, and it's still simple.

Edit: After further testing, I'm not actually sure why what you're doing isn't working. Once I added `var circles = d3.selectAll('circle');` to the beginning, the function B loop works fine, assuming you *actually clicked a circle before running it*. If you didn't, you're iterating over an empty array.

Answer (score 5):

From D3's point of view there are some improvements applicable to your approach which will make your code much more readable and *D3ish*. Try to work your way through D3's [concept of selections](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/selection/) to get a good understanding of it. Even without knowing your entire code, the snippets posted in your question might be refactored to something like this:

```
// From outer function
// This will hold the selection in the outer scope.
var selections;

// From inner function A
circles.on("click", function(da){
  // Fill in the reference to the selection which is returned by filter().
  selections = d3.selectAll("circle").filter(function(db){
    return da.someProperty == db.someProperty;
  })
  .attr("fill", "red");
});

// From inner function B
// No need for an explicit loop here; D3 will take care of that.
selections.attr("fill", "black");
```

The `filter()` function will return the selection you are after without the need to fiddle around with any auxiliary arrays. You just store the reference to this selection in `selections` saving it in the outer scope.

When, later on, you somehow want to act on this selection, there is no need for an explicit loop over an array because D3 will take care of that. You may just call its methods for dealing with attributes, styles, event handlers, etc. See the [API docs](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections) for all methods, which are available on `d3.select()`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nevseev/0g7w6zhf/1/)

```
var jsonCircles = [{
    "x_axis": 30,
        "y_axis": 30,
        "radius": 20,
        "color": "green"
}, {
    "x_axis": 70,
        "y_axis": 70,
        "radius": 20,
        "color": "purple"
}, {
    "x_axis": 110,
        "y_axis": 100,
        "radius": 20,
        "color": "red"
}, {
    "x_axis": 150,
        "y_axis": 230,
        "radius": 70,
        "color": "yellow"
}, {
    "x_axis": 300,
        "y_axis": 100,
        "radius": 90,
        "color": "grey"
}];

var svgContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", 400)
    .attr("height", 400);

var circles = svgContainer.selectAll("circle")
    .data(jsonCircles)
    .enter()
    .append("circle");

var circleAttributes = circles.attr("cx", function (d) {
    return d.x_axis;
})
    .attr("cy", function (d) {
    return d.y_axis;
})
    .attr("r", function (d) {
    return d.radius;
})
    .style("fill", function (d) {
    return d.color;
});

var selection = [];

d3.selectAll('circle')[0].forEach(function (circle) {
    if (circle.r.baseVal.value > 20) {
        selection.push(circle);
    }
});

alert('We have ' + selection.length + 'circle(s) selected');
selection.forEach(function (circle) {
    circle.style.fill = "blue";
});
```